# MySQL Complex Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table that contains a keyword_id, site_id, percentage.

Now I use:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     keyword_relations
WHERE    keyword_id = "game"
ORDER BY percentage DESC,
LIMIT    {$page}, {$limitperpage}
```

Now lets say on page 26 according to this SQL a website called "example.com" appears.

Now lets say that I want to get the row number where a keyword on example.com, how can I do that.

For example, if example.com is ranked 5th on page 6 for keyword "examples" then how do I get the page number when I have the website "example.com" and the keyword "examples" from a different page.

I am trying to find the page number where the website should appear by dividing the the row number of the ranking of a website for a keyword (sorted by keywords occurrence) by the limit_per_page.

Comment: count(*) usually helps. with a condition, of course

Comment: well thanks @Col. Shrapnel. I would appreciate if you could help me further as I know that count(*) usually helps. But in this case it is a bit different.

Comment: The question is very confusing. There's page 26, then page 6 then.. please try rephrasing and possibly adding some sample data rows.

Comment: i am sorry @Richard aka cyberwiki. I could not explain the question well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$per_page_limit = 20;
$sql = "SELECT count(k_id) as k_id FROM keywords_relations WHERE k_id = '{$row['k_id']}' AND percent >= '{$row['percent']}'";
$data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
$k_ids = $data['k_id'] + 1;
//is_int($k_page) ? floor($k_page) : floor($k_page) + 1;
if($k_ids % $per_page_limit ){
    $k_page = floor($k_ids/$per_page_limit) + 1;         
} else {
    $k_page = $k_ids/$per_page_limit;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT   *, @row:=@row+1 AS Row_Number
FROM     keyword_relations, (SELECT @row:=0) r
WHERE    keyword_id = "game"
ORDER BY percentage DESC,
LIMIT    {$page}, {$limitperpage}
```

I think, given [what I could find](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,192721,225575#msg-225575)

Note: Change the `:=0` assignment to the value of `{$page}*{$limitperpage}`

**EDIT**

If you're interested in page, try the following:

```
SELECT    *, FLOOR((@row/5)+1) AS Page_Number, @row:=@row+1 AS Row_Number
FROM      keyword_relations,
          (SELECT @row:={$page}*{$limitperpage}) r
WHERE     keyword_id = "game"
ORDER BY  percentage DESC
LIMIT     {$page},{$limitperpage}
```

Comment: let me try this and I will get back to you in a moment

Comment: Hi, I am trying to find the page number by dividing the the row number of the ranking of a website for a keyword by the limit_per_page. The query above does not work.

Comment: @user381595: You can use `FLOOR(((@row:=@row+1)-1)/5)+1 AS PAGE` in your query if you'd like, but note you need to use either or.

Comment: @user381595: Try my new query in my answer, see if that doesn't help.

Comment: sorry, but if just have the site and the keyword but not the page then how do i get the page number, the query you just submitted also has a $page in limit which is what i am trying to get. thanks

Comment: @user381595: Then `$page` isn't a good variable name, it's more similar to a `$start`. Assuming you have 100 entries and 10 per page, and you're "paging" by using the row index, you can divide the row index by the page (but you need the `floor()` result back). e.g. 9/10=0.9, and the floor of that is 0. but 10/10=1, the floor is still 1 so it's the next page.